# Mongo db how to return document in one to many relationship?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I want to make a collection which look like this:

```
{
    _id: "id1",
    "name": "A"
}

{
    _id: "id2",
    name: "B",
    supervisor: "id1"
}

{
    _id: "id3",
    name: "C",
    supervisor: "id1"
}
```

Each person can have at most one supervisor and a person cannot supervise and be supervised at the same time.

So how can i query to get the results in a form like this:

```
{
    _id: "id1",
    supervise: [
        {
            _id: "id2",
            name: "B",
            supervisor: "id1"
        },
        {
            _id: "id3",
            name: "C",
            supervisor: "id1"   
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation with a group by `$supervisor` and `$push` elements in an array :

```
db.device.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$supervisor", supervise: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
   ]
)
```

It will return for you data :

```
{ "_id" : "id1", "supervise" : [ { "_id" : "id2", "name" : "B", "supervisor" : "id1" }, { "_id" : "id3", "name" : "C", "supervisor" : "id1" } ] }
{ "_id" : null, "supervise" : [ { "_id" : "id1", "name" : "A" } ] }
```

Check mongodb [`$group` aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)